# Creating MDF tables using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server-localdb, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.  In Explore Server, I create a new `DB.mdf` file.

When I right click on "Tables" I don't have the option to create a new table.

Do I need to install something in order to create MDF files' tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate way to do this with visual studio is to:

1. Install SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio.
2. Create a SQL Database project.
3. Use the tools within the project to create and modify your database objects.
4. Use the publish feature to push your changes to the database.

Using a DB project allows you to easily leverage source control, and define build configurations for your databases.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Professional. According to MSDN, I should be able to create tables using VS. What's happening? I'll install SQL Server Data  Tools.

Comment: Installing SQL Server Data Tools has solved my issue. "Add new table" is now available. Next project I'll create a dedicated SQL Database project. Thank you